# How to use sed 's/$var/$var2' file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I'm trying to replace a value shown as a variable with another value shown as a second variable, using the following line:

```
    sed -i "s/$header/$new/" file.f
```

Where "$header" is the old variable I want replaced with the new one ($new).

I'm getting this error:

```
    sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'
```

I've tried

```
    sed -i 's/$header/$new/' file.f
    sed -i "s/$header/$new/" file.f
    sed -i 's/"$header"/"$new"/' file.f
```

None of it seem to work.
How should I write this line so I can get the right output (replacing '$header' with '$new' on the file)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are values of both variables?

Comment: As lurker mentioned, use `sed 's/\$header/\$new/'`. Also on a side note, O suggest to first test the `sed` command without `-i` and verify the output on screen. Once you are sure that it is working the way you expected, add `-i`.

Comment: @lurker the variables are expanded before sed even starts, so that doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @Utsav I have no idea what you think your suggested code will do.

Comment: I tried your way and it works. Can you share what is your $header and $new?

Comment: @op, you'll have to show us the contents of the variables but at a guess they contain `/` and you will need a different delimiter.

Comment: Do you want to replace literally `$header` with `$new`, or the values of variables called `header` and `new`?

Comment: @123 - It would change $header with $new literally, which I think is what OP is trying to ask.

Comment: @Utsav the title says variables and the first thing they tried `sed -i 's/$header/$new/'` would have worked if that were the case. You would only need to escape `$` if it were the last char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/$old/$new/" file
```

works fine. You can change the separtor if your data has the character /.

```
sed -i "s@$old@$new@" file
```

Comment: Try with `$old=foo/bar` value!

Comment: Try sed "s@$old@$new" file

Comment: You should also realize that any regex special characters in `$old` (the pattern) need to be escaped and in the replacement `$new` the back slash is special in needs to be escaped.

Comment: `"s@$old@$new@"`, with the trailing `@`. and what @fd0 just said about escaping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure of the content of the variables and to reduce clashing the separator you can use

```
sed "s^A$old^A$new^A"
```

to enter the `CTRL-A` press `CTRL-V + CTRL-A` (or any other value not expected in vars)